# How to receive and return string in webapp2 from android?

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am struggling to receive a string into my webapp2 server.
The android device is supposed to send a string `name`to the server then the server returns back to the phone `"your name is: " + name`.

The server is only returning to android`"your name is: "` because the `name` string seems to be null on the server side.
I am not sure if the problem is on android or server side.

My code is as follows:

**ANDROID.java**

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try  {
                    String name = "Jay";
                    String serverURL = "http://myapp.appspot.com";
                    URL url = new URL(serverURL);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    try{
                        httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
                        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                        OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                        String post_data = URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8");
                        writer.write(post_data);
                        writer.flush();
                        writer.close();
                        outputStream.close();

                        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                        String result="";
                        String line="";
                        while((line = reader.readLine())!= null)
                            result += line;
                        reader.close();
                        inputStream.close();

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
```

**SERVER.py**

```
import webapp2


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get('content')
        self.response.out.write("Your name is: " + name)

    def get(self):
        self.response.write("Hello World")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `name = self.request.get('content')` statement most likely doesn't do what you're expecting it to.

Since post data is sent in the message body you probably want to look at `self.request.body` instead (I'm not a java user, I can't tell exactly how your post data is organized inside the body).

From `webapp2`'s [Request data](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/request.html):

> **POST data**
>
> Variables url encoded in the body of a request (generally a POST form
>   submitted using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` media type)
>   are available in `request.POST`. It is also a [MultiDict](http://docs.webob.org/en/stable/api/multidict.html) and can
>   be accessed in the same way as `.GET`. Examples:
>
> ```
> request = Request.blank('/')
> request.method = 'POST'
> request.body = 'check=a&check=b&name=Bob'
>
> # The whole MultiDict:
> # POST([('check', 'a'), ('check', 'b'), ('name', 'Bob')])
> post_values = request.POST
>
> # The last value for a key: 'b'
> check_value = request.POST['check']
>
> # All values for a key: ['a', 'b']
> check_values = request.POST.getall('check')
>
> # An iterable with all items in the MultiDict:
> # [('check', 'a'), ('check', 'b'), ('name', 'Bob')]
> request.POST.items()
> ```
>
> Like `GET`, the name `POST` is a somewhat misleading, but has
>   historical reasons: they are also available when the HTTP method is
>   PUT, and not only POST.

Comment: So I changed        name = self.request.get('content')        to      name = self.request.body              and that made the difference. Now it is properly returning the name string. Thank you.